# How do you show Facebook friend count on your site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I simply want to display in a WordPress blog the number of friends a user has.

I had this FQL code:

```
function fb_count(){
     $fb_id = '00000000'; //Facebook id, which I don't want to put here. 
     $count = get_transient('fb5_count');
     if ($count !== false) return (int)$count[1];
     $count = 0;
     $data = wp_remote_get('https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+friend_count+FROM+user+WHERE+uid='.$fb_id.'');
     if (is_wp_error($data)) {
        return 'Error!!';
    }else{
        preg_match('/(\d+)/', $data[body], $count);
    }
    set_transient('fb5_count', $count, 60*60*24); // 24 hour cache
    return (int)$count[1];
}
```

Now that FQL has been deprecated, how can I get a friend count without a token? Or how do I get a token for a non-app thing like this?

Comment: The user need to have granted `user_friends` permission to your app. Then you can just do a call to /me/friends to get number of friends

Comment: @WizKid That's my problem, I don't have an "app". How do I get a token or grant permissions for a website?

Comment: You have to have an app. There is no way around it